# How to write a query to get values from a table filter(WHERE clause) based on multiple value field?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table in MySQL for products, fields are described below,

```
id      productname     price   currency      description      category
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
34      xxxx            50      USD           xyxyxyxyxyx       54,65
35      xxyy            60      USD           xyxyxyxyxyx       52,75
36      yyxx            70      USD           xyxyxyxyxyx       24,85
37      yyyy            20      USD           xyxyxyxyxyx       65,52
```

I'm in a situation that a product could be available in different category. So I'm storing multiple category with comma delimiters as above table.

Now I wanted to retrieve products from specific category, for eg., to retrieve products of category 52.

The result should be like this

```
id      productname     price   currency      description   category
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
35      xxyy            60      USD           xyxyxyxyxyx       52,75
37      yyyy            20      USD           xyxyxyxyxyx       65,52
```

How to write a query to get this result?

Thank you very much in advance!.

Comment: You should **not** store multiple values in one column... A database is not a pseudonym for a CSV file. Use a link table.

Comment: You should change the database schema and add a `products_categories` table with `product_id` and `category_id`.

Comment: In other words see normalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with using the [FIND_IN_SET(str,strlist)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) method,

```
select * from tablename where FIND_IN_SET('52',category) > 0
```